# What's the proper way to create a BUILD method in MooseX::Declare?

Tags: perl, moose

I am having difficulty with the `BUILD` method in [MooseX::Declare](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-Declare).  If I say:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use MooseX::Declare;

class Foo {
    has foo => (is => "rw", isa => "Str", default => "foo");

    method BUILD {
        print "I was called\n";
    }
}

Foo->new;
```

I get the following less than helpful error message:

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected at /Users/cowens/perl5/lib/perl5/MooseX/Method/Signatures/Meta/Method.pm line 335.
Validation failed for 'MooseX::Types::Structured::Tuple[MooseX::Types::Structured::Tuple[Object],MooseX::Types::Structured::Dict[]]' failed with value [ [ Foo=HASH(0x804b20) ], { HASH(0x8049e0) => undef } ], Internal Validation Error is: Validation failed for 'MooseX::Types::Structured::Dict[]' failed with value { HASH(0x8049e0) => undef } at /Users/cowens/perl5/lib/perl5/MooseX/Method/Signatures/Meta/Method.pm line 365
        MooseX::Method::Signatures::Meta::Method::validate('MooseX::Method::Signatures::Meta::Method=HASH(0xb8aab0)', 'ARRAY(0xb8ab30)') called at /Users/cowens/perl5/lib/perl5/MooseX/Method/Signatures/Meta/Method.pm line 139
        Foo::BUILD('Foo=HASH(0x804b20)', 'HASH(0x8049e0)') called at generated method (unknown origin) line 25
        Foo::new('Foo') called at test.pl line 13
```

But if I say:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use MooseX::Declare;

class Foo {
    has foo => (is => "rw", isa => "Str", default => "foo");

    sub BUILD {
        my $self = shift;
        print "I was called\n";
    }
}

Foo->new;
```

everything works just fine (but is ugly and out of place with the rest of the code).

Answer (score 6):

BUILD takes an arg, if you don't need it, just say:

```
method BUILD($) { ... }
```

Answer (score 5):

It's failing because `BUILD` requires a one-arg method signature. By default, `MooseX::Declare` creates a signature which is not compatible with the way `BUILD` is called. (The details are murky to me.) I know because I ran into a similar error once. I certainly agree the error message could be more enlightening; that's true with a lot of Moose stuff.

Anyway, I got it to work like this:

```
use MooseX::Declare;

class Foo {
    has foo => (is => "rw", isa => "Str", default => "foo");

    method BUILD(Item $href) {
        print "I was called\n";
    }
}

Foo->new;
```

Hope that helps.

You can fiddle with the signature and try more specific types; I think Moose sends a hashref of the as-yet-unblessed object as the parameter.

Comment: Wow, that is ugly, `$self` exists and holds the blessed object, but you also have this useless hashref full of the arguments passed into `new`.  This is a major wart on what is otherwise a beautiful system.

Comment: This "wart" maybe something that will be removed.  When you look at old docs (http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose-0.65/lib/Moose/Cookbook/Basics/Recipe4.pod) you will see that extra param hashref arg is needed.  However in new docs (http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Cookbook/Basics/Recipe4.pod) you can now use $self direct to access the "params".  So perhaps part of an evolutionary process where this extra param will be dropped off!   Moose mailing list / IRC is best place to find out  whether "params" arg is still needed and what the Darwinian plans are ;-)

Comment: An argument to a method is a "major wart"?  I would hate to hear what you think of the C++ or Java object system...

Comment: BUILD is used to finish up Instance creation. It is passed a copy of the arguments sent to new() so that it can deal with any arguments in their original state (or at least the state they come out of BUILDARGS in). I don't see how an argument to enable the basic function of a code block is a "wart", and I'm fairly certain that the arguments won't change anytime soon.

Answer (score -2):

Perl understands `sub` and so an entry into the current package's symbol table is made. &Foo::BUILD, after [Devel::Declare](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::Declare) and other magic has created a package scope from the class closure.

[Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) specifically looks for the `BUILD` sub to allow you to manipulate constructor logic. My guess (although I haven't traced it all the way through) is that the MooseX modules stay out of the way of what Moose is trying to do. So that a native `BUILD` is forever passed to the Moose magic to determine constructor logic.

On the other hand the `method` keyword is more [Devel::Declare](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::Declare) magic to create methods in the meta class structure.